# How pivot month name in SQL Server after a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with these columns:

```
id int pk
date datetime 
value numeric
```

This is my select query

```
SELECT      
    O.Date AS DATE,
    O.Value AS VALUE    
FROM 
    Orders O
WHERE 
    YEAR(Date) = @Year
```

and this is my data

[image]

I want this output:

```
JAN   FEB    MAR   APR   MAY  JUNE  JULY   AUG   SEPT   OCT   NOV   DEC
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
600   1200   600   600    0     0     0     0      0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Please tag the database name you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't need a subquery.  Something like this should work

```
select sum(case when dt.mo=1 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Jan',
       sum(case when dt.mo=2 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Feb',
       sum(case when dt.mo=3 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Mar',
       sum(case when dt.mo=4 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Apr',
       sum(case when dt.mo=5 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'May',
       sum(case when dt.mo=6 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Jun',
       sum(case when dt.mo=7 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Jul',
       sum(case when dt.mo=8 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Aug',
       sum(case when dt.mo=9 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Sep',
       sum(case when dt.mo=10 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Oct',
       sum(case when dt.mo=11 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Nov',
       sum(case when dt.mo=12 then o.[Value] else 0 end) 'Dec'
from Orders o
     cross apply (select month(o.[Date]) mo) dt
where year(o.[DAte])=@Year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this-

```
 Select 
  max(case when [Month] = 'Jan' then Value end) As "JAN"
 ,max(case when [Month] = 'Feb' then Value end) As "FEB"
 ,.....
 ,max(case when [Month] = 'Dec' then Value end) As "DEC"
 from
 (SELECT
    Format(O.Date, 'MMM') as [Month],
    Max(O.Value) AS VALUE    
 FROM Orders O
 WHERE YEAR(Date) = @Year
 Group by 
    Format(O.Date, 'MMM'))T;
```